# ClassNotFoundError while running java program

Tags: java

I am running a program using a .sh file. The .java file has the `main()` method and inside it I have an object instantiated from a class of other .java files. It compiled successfully, but when it comes down to executing the file, it shows `

> ClassNotFoundException

`in the`main()`method for the first object creation, even though there was a .class file created for`FetchData`.

```
package scheduledExecutor;

public class Executor
{
    public static void main()
    {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        FetchData task= new FetchData(); -- show error here for ClassNotFound
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 310, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You're missing the closing bracket for your  `Executor` class

Comment: Or the main method...we can't tell from here.

Comment: Please share full error message - it'll helps to understand concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting FetchData class location in file path and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You get a ClassNotFoundException at execution time but not during compilation when the path for the compiler includes the class but the ClassPath for the JVM does not include the target class.

Make sure the folder or jar that contains the FetchData class file is in the ClassPath of the JVM when you run the program.  Look at the difference between the compiler's Classpath and the one used by the JVM.